# Prefill input text with LaravelCollective

Tags: laravel-5, laravelcollective

I have a Laravel 5.2 application, I have a form with a lot of elements (checkboxes,selects, inputs file, input text, etc). So, I'm using the *Form & HTML* extension of **LaravelCollective** 
So, I'm using form::model to bind the model to the form, that's working great with all the elements except with the input text, and a email element. I have this:

```
{!! Form::model($mymodel,array('url'=>'myurl','method'=>'POST')) !!}
    {!!  Form::email('mail', $value = null, $attributes = array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
    {!! Form::text('Username', '', array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Then, listing the attributes that I have in the model (I made `dd($mymodel)` and copied only the *fillable*):

```
array:25 [▼
    0 => "mail"
    1 => "Username"
  ]
```

The others attributes are prefilled properly, except input text and input mail.

Answer (score 0):

The field names need to match the columns in your Model. The column names are usually lower-case.

The email field should be:

```
Form::email('mail', null, array('class'=>'form-control'))
```

I.e. it should NOT have `$value = null` or `$attributes = ...`

I would also set the username field to `null`:

```
Form::text('Username', null, array('class' => 'form-control'))
```